# How to edit data with dynamic TableView with dynamic column in JAVAFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

Today This is the demo to show data from **CSV for DAT file without make custom class** on tableView in JavaFX 2.0. I call this TableView as Dynamic TableView because the tableview automatically manages the columns and rows. 

 On my research about the editable on tableView we must have a custom class and implement it to tableView to show as this demo ==>   http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

But in this case I can not do it because we don't know how many column example with csv file or .dat file.... I want to do **editable on this tableView in this case** by add TextField into TableCell. How does it do without make custom class (because you do not how many column ...), and if **it must make custom class** then how about **the design of custom class for this case**?

Could you please help me?

```
    private void getDataDetailWithDynamic() {
    tblView.getItems().clear();
    tblView.getColumns().clear();
    tblView.setPlaceholder(new Label("Loading..."));
        //            @Override



            try {
                File aFile = new File(txtFilePath.getText());
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(aFile));
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

                final String headerLine = in.readLine();
                final String[] headerValues = headerLine.split("\t");
                        for (int column = 0; column < headerValues.length; column++) {
                            tblView.getColumns().add(
                                    createColumn(column, headerValues[column]));
                        }

                // Data:

                String dataLine;
                while ((dataLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    final String[] dataValues = dataLine.split("\t");
                            // Add additional columns if necessary:
                            for (int columnIndex = tblView.getColumns().size(); columnIndex < dataValues.length; columnIndex++) {
                                tblView.getColumns().add(createColumn(columnIndex, ""));
                            }
                            // Add data to table:
                            ObservableList<StringProperty> data = FXCollections
                                    .observableArrayList();
                            for (String value : dataValues) {
                                data.add(new SimpleStringProperty(value));
                            }
                            tblView.getItems().add(data);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("ex: " + ex.toString());
            }


    for(int i=0; i<tblView.getColumns().size(); i++) {
        TableColumn col = (TableColumn)tblView.getColumns().get(i);
        col.setPrefWidth(70);
    }
}

private TableColumn createColumn(
        final int columnIndex, String columnTitle) {
    TableColumn column = new TableColumn(DefaultVars.BLANK_CHARACTER);
    String title;
    if (columnTitle == null || columnTitle.trim().length() == 0) {
        title = "Column " + (columnIndex + 1);
    } else {
        title = columnTitle;
    }


            Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {

                    System.out.println("event cell");
                    EditingCellData cellExtend = new EditingCellData();
                    return cellExtend;
                }
            };

    column.setText(title);
    column.setCellValueFactory(cellFactory);
    return column;
}
```

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Excellent first question and welcome to SO!

Comment: I'm a little confused.  In order for the JavaFX TableView to automatically update itself, it has to be able to receive notification events from your data source.  In order for your data source to send notification events, it must meet the minimum definition for a JavaFX Property (JavaFX Bean).  In other words, you need to have a data model object with properties corresponding to your columns.  If you do not already have this, then I don't think you can have a TableView that is "dynamic".

Comment: Hi scottb, sorry about your confuse in this case. I've edited my problem again, please read again. My idea is a read content from csv with many column that you don't know how many column and load it in to the tableView, beside it I want edit data on it and save the content. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I can load it in tableView but I want to edit data on it by add textfield to TableCell.... How does it do?

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way to resolve it ==> https://forums.oracle.com/message/11216643#11216643

I'm really thank for your reading about that.

Thanks